# Including CSS in Head does not seem to work in current version 9.33

Tags: 2sxc, dotnetnuke

Including CSS in head like this does not seem to work in current version 9.33. Is this a known bug?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@App.Path/dist/css/style.css" data-enableoptimizations="150:head"/>
```

So its included, but not in the head and the data-enableoptimizations attribute is being rendered in the HTML code.

Comment: This is the first we hear of this, so I want to be sure it's not a mistake on your side. Pls verify that your DNN has the right settings for client-depency etc. If you think it's still an issue, pls post on github.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding CSS in the theme, it's probably better to use dnnCSSInclude.

Here is a place to start:  https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/client-resource-management-api.  Ignore that the reference is to DNN 6.x, as this applies to all subsequent versions of DNN.

Comment: Also, the 40fingers stylehelper skin object provides lots of other tools:  https://www.40fingers.net/Products/DNN-Stylehelper

Comment: This thread is about the 2SexyContent Module, not about the skin/theme. But thanks for your engagement.

Answer (score 0):

Along with using the `dnncssinclude` object, make sure that object has an attribute `forceprovider` set to `DnnPageHeaderProvider`, to force it to be rendered inside the `<head>`.